# drupal : how to share corecode and modules(core + extra) different domain with same hosting?

Tags: php, drupal-7

Q : drupal : how to share corecode and modules(core + extra) different domain with same hosting?

I've 2 domain at same hosting.

e.g
domainA.com and domainB.com

I setup a drupal 7.17 (original) into domainA.com

At that time I want to use the corecode and modules (core + extra) of domainA.com from domainB.com. How can I use like this?

Thx for any advice

Answer (score 0):

I always use the backup option of my control panel.

My webhosting party provides me with DirectAdmin control panel. From there I can export one account (files, database and everything) to a backup file. Then on another account I can choose to resore that backup.

It is fast and leaves all references intact.